# window.requestAnimationFrame is not a function

Tags: angular-universal, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

I am using angular universal for my project, and for showing the pdf using ng2-pdf-viewer plugins but it is giving me the error `Unhandled Promise rejection: window.requestAnimationFrame is not a function` while i have already imported windows and documents in server.js.

"Can anyone please help me how I can resolve this problem"

Comment: Hi Faraz. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: You mean to include ng2-pdf-viewer not ng2-pdfjs-viewer